# how Improve Build Error Reporting on ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I  just created a react app using

**npm create-react-app my-app**

I like this error reporting in chrome and on CLI.
Is there a way so i can configure or setup such error reporting in my existing React application ?
because when i setup react app by following a number of tutorials i do not see this nice output. thanks. You can see the images below for instance.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After exploring the repository i found **create-react-app** using 
[react-error-overlay](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/next/packages/react-error-overlay) module. 
See this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/error-overlay-webpack-plugin) if somebody wants to setup in your existing react application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess...
you typo wrong. 
error previous line `<dvs` remove this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it is not about error, it is about error reporting. plz read question carefully.

Comment: hmm.. find `<dvs` in your code. and remove it. because it is wrong

Comment: @sm.abdullah I don't understand.. -1